# Get Image from server

Tags: ios, json, image, afnetworking

I am getting responseObject like this

> responseObject =
>       {
>           "img": "images/ProfileImage/defaultImg.jpg",
>       }

I have to store this image in app folder. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Whats full URL for image? what ever you posted as object is not having fullpath, it can't be downloaded from server without fullpath.

Comment: if u get only single path , why u unncessary save into folder, just add into NSuserdefault its enought

Comment: OP wants to store image into directory not URL.

Answer (score 0):

The path is incomplete

You need to append base URL before "images/ProfileImage/defaultImg.jpg"

Then

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSString *urlToDownload = BaseURL + "images/ProfileImage/defaultImg.jpg";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if (urlData)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"defaultImg.png"];
        //saving is done on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File Saved !");
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I am able to create folder in document directory. but i need to create folder in phone for app. ex. in android phone if we download whatsApp it will show whatsApp folder in My files/sdcard and in whatsApp folder there will be different folders like WhatsApp Images, WhatsApp Video, WhatsApp Documents etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for downloading image and store into a local i.e "Document" directory in iOS app folder

In below code `urlString` is the url of image.

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadThumbNail = dispatch_queue_create("com.download.thumbnail", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadThumbNail, ^
    {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        UIImage *imageThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            NSString *str = @“filename.png”;
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
            NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageThumb);
            [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        });
    });
```

Enjoy codeing.

Comment: hey this will  create folder in pc but i want to create folder iPhone having appName in which there wl be 2 folder profileImage and postImage. and i want to store this images in profileImage Folder.